# Google shopping API country code not working except for US

Tags: google-api, google-shopping-api

Hi I'm trying to call this url `https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key="my key"&country=US&q=9780198062257&alt=json` on the browser.

It works fine and gave the appropriate data but when I change the country form US to IN (India) or any other country code, it gives zero results even though it works fine through Google shopping search.

Can any one tell how to search for every country? I know ISO 3166 code are the country code but they are not working. Please help on how to call this url country wise.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Google Product Search API does not work for India. Here is a [list of countries](http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?answer=160619) for which this API will work.

Comment: its not working for the given list in your links.its only working for US.when i put country code=CN(china its not showing result.its only give result entry for US.